# Is there a way to hide the Standard NAME field?

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-object, record, user-record, standard-field

Is there a way to delete/hide this field? It comes with object creation but I don't need it. Or is there a flow /formula field I can do to update this field with the user? This is for a tab called Managers where the regional manager can see all the managers under him and can click on each name and see the projects each is working on, etc. Please help me. Thank you!
[image: Record name Field-Comes with object creation]

Comment: Maybe change Name to Auto-Number? 
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325368&type=1

Comment: You may well find you do need it since many parts of the Salesforce UI need this field (e.g. in list views or related lists) in order to provide a link to the record's own page.

Comment: I want it, I just want it to be a look-up to  Users (First+Last Name) assigned as managers. I didn't want users to be typing names freely- misspelling, person not a manager, etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice.  All objects have a set of mandatory fields, and this is one of them.  You can choose for it to be a text field or an auto-number value.

If you don't have much use for this field, that's fine; set it to auto-number then hide it from the page layout (or display it down the bottom of the page layout).